# Why is Swift ViewController not able to add subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to work with a view controller in SwiftUI. I want to add a text label as a subview on the view controller, but any subview I add is not displayed on the screen. The code is as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.appear()
    }
    
func appear() {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello, World!"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
        label.textColor = UIColor.green
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        print("adding text")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in
            self!.view.addSubview(label)}
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        print ("text added")
    }
```

Only a blue background is displayed but the text is not. I even added two print statements to check if the code block is even executed, and it is but for some reason the text is not displayed. Any help to fix this will be much appreciated.

ps: I am displaying this view controller as a swift view inside a VStack by using a UIViewControllerRepresentable wrapper for the view controller.

Comment: You have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`. Ute you haven't added any constraints

Comment: To put it another way, your label has neither size nor position. It is an invisible dot.

Comment: even when I remove the constraint, the text is not displayed

Comment: Because it still has neither size nor position. Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true and assign the label a _frame_. Or set it to false and add top and leading _constraints_.

Comment: Ohh didn’t know label needed it’s own size and position apart from the text itself.

Comment: How abt for a gradient layer? I’m adding a CAGradientLayer() and even set it’s frame size/position using CGRect, but the layer is not displayed on the view

Comment: Please add some code that illustrates how you add the gradient layer. Also, you don't need to add the label asychronously, nor you need to call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` in `viewDidLoad`. The layout pass will anyway happen before the view is presented regardless of these calls.

Comment: I realised for gradient layer I needed to use UIColor.x.cgColor instead of UIColor.x so its fine now